# Formatting of position in Story View

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story

I'm looking at the *Position or Team* story type in Story View. This bug may or may not apply to other story types. In the below screenshots, the phrase *Voice Reservations* should be italicized.

## Closed, "Less"

Here, it is not italicized:
[image]

## Open, "More"

Here, it is, as it should be:
[image]

---

Apologies, my screen-shot program does not automatically insert hand-drawn circles. If need be, I can add them by hand.

Comment: Hmm. I had assumed this was a simple bug, but now I'm guessing it was a design choice to leave formatting out of the shortened view. (Not sure why.) In this case, the text doesn't make much sense without the list formatting to delineate the separate ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now fixed: markdown is rendered on both collapsed and expanded view.

Comment: You should add a [tag:status-completed] to this to indicate that its completed and fixed now.

Comment: @Magisch Thanks, forgot to do it ;)

Comment: Perfect, and magical! Thanks!